# Diffrence between 花生米 and 花生

Tags: translation

What's the difference between `花生米` and `花生`? Does `花生米` mean `peanut without shell`, while the `花生` is `peanut in general`?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The peanut is a very interesting plant. The flowers send out "pegs" which burrow into the ground, where the peanuts are formed. That's why they are called 落花生 ("droop from the flower born"), but they develop underground!

Answer (score 3):

Michal Rosenbaum's interpretation is theoretically correct but the actual usage of both terms can be ambiguous. 花生 refers to the plant general that produces peanuts, but it can also refer to peanuts, with or without shells. 花生米 on the other hand refers to the seeds of peanut as 米 stands for grain-shaped objects. It mainly refers to peanuts without shell, but some people also use it to refer to peanut with shells. There is also a term 花生仁 that unambiguously refers to peanuts without shells and 去皮花生仁 that refers to skinned peanuts without shells.